# Injecting FacesContext as managed property of session-scoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-1.2, facescontext

I had a request-scoped JSF 1.2 managed bean that I needed to refactor to session-scoped bean because it is doing some expensive operation on `@PostConstruct` and that is being called multiple times which really needs to be done only once. The side effect of changing the scope to session is now I cannot inject `FacesContext` anymore in `faces-config.xml` by doing like this:

```
<managed-property>
 <property-name>context</property-name>
 <value>#{facesContext}</value>
</managed-property>
```

where I have

```
setContext(FacesContext ctx) {}
```

in my managed bean.

In one of my action methods I need the context to access `ExternalContext`/`HttpServletResponse`. I don't want to invoke

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

inside my action method but somehow call `setContext(FacesContext ctx)` externally to allow isolation of context injection for ease of mocked testing. I tried putting the `setContext()` inside the `@PostConstruct` only to realize later that `FacesContext` is a per request thing and my `ExternalContext` was reset to `null` once a new request is being submitted.

How could I call `setContext(FacesContext ctx)` auto-magically every time I hit a new request although the managed bean itself is session scoped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your request scoped bean and inject the session scoped bean in it instead so that you can pass the `FacesContext` to it in the `@PostConstruct` of the request scoped bean. In the session scoped bean, perform lazy loading/executing.

E.g.

```
public class RequestBean {

    private FacesContext context; // Managed property.
    private SessionBean sessionBean; // Managed property.

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sessionBean.init(context);
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
public class SessionBean {

    private SomeObject initializedObject;

    public void init(FacesContext context) {
        if (initializedObject != null) {
            return;
        }

        initializedObject = initializeObject(context);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating two separate managed beans like you suggested to solve the problem. I was struggling earlier because I tried to fit into a single managed bean.

Comment: You're welcome. The only way to inject `FacesContext` in a session scoped bean is using CDI, but that's only available when you're using Java EE 6. As you're using the ancient JSF 1.2, that's clearly completely out of the question.

Comment: How would you do it with CDI?

Comment: ... do you mean via @Provides?